# How do I delete records with rearranged ides

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

My problem is that I want code similar to the code I will put forward, where it deletes the selected elements and then arranges the remaining elements, for example: if you delete

```
1-2-3-5-6
delete  2-3 
1-2-3
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work if the selection is greater than two

```
module.exports.deleteSelected = function(ids, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        db.run(`DELETE FROM mean_t WHERE id = ?`, [ids[i]], function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return callback({ success: false, message: 'حدث خطأ أثناء عملية الحذف' });
            }

            if (i === ids.length - 1) {
                db.run(`UPDATE or IGNORE  mean_t SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > ?`, [ids[ids.length - 1]], function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return callback({ success: false, message: 'تم حذف السجلات، ولكن حدث خطأ أثناء تحديث الـ ID للسجلات المتبقية' });
                    }

                    return callback({ success: true, message: 'تم حذف السجلات بنجاح' });
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Changing IDs is usually a bad idea. IDs are often used as references in other tables, so you'd need to update all the references. Why do you feel you need to do this?

Comment: I don't need it in other tables

Comment: Anyway, the problem with your solution is that DB operations are asynchronous. So you're not waiting for the renumbering after the first ID is deleted before you delete the second ID. If you redesign to use `await` it should be easier to solve this.

Comment: Still, why do you think you need all the IDs to be sequential? If you're not referencing the IDs in other tables, why do you even have them?

Comment: I needed them to appear in the interface in order, but you are really right. Why would I need that? I will use a regular variable on the interface

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGiJo.png)

You can adapt this logic to your Node.js code by replacing the example array with your database records and updating the array modification part based on your specific needs. Note that in a real-world scenario with a database, you would typically handle this logic in a more sophisticated manner, using transactions and ensuring data integrity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) Also, have you taken the [tour]? (You get the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) badge after you do.